# Fluid div with 100% width

Tags: html, css, width

I have a html structure like the one below with a sidebar and a main container. What I want is to have a fixed width of the sidebar (and later on change it with media queries) and a main container that's fluid. This means that if I'm decreasing the browsers width the main container should decrease in width but not the sidebar.

I've tried 100% width of #container, 15% width of the sidebar and 85% width of the main container but this (of course) decreases the width of the sidebar as well. Only using 100% width of the main container and a fixed width of the sidebar container doesn't seem to work.

What is the best way of solving this?

**html:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
        //content
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        //content
    </div>
</div>

 ________________________
|     |                  |
|     |                  |
|     |                  |
|     |                  |
|     |                  |
|     |                  |
|     |                  |
|     |                  |
--------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following css

```
.container{display:block; padding:0 0 0 200px;}
.sidebar{display:block; float:left; width:200px; margin:0 0 0 -200px;}
.main{display:block; width:100%}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/3ApFZ/

**Css** :

```
#sidebar{
    width:150px;
    position: absolute;
    background:blue;
    height:100%;

}
#main{
    width:100%;
    padding-left: 150px;
    background:red;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: haha both our fiddles are identical. I guess two people can't be wrong huh. We'll see what the OP thinks :)

Comment: @LOTUSMS The problem : When  we look : 0 answer, when we post : 4 answers ;) everything in 40s...

Comment: @TheLittePig :thumbs up:

Answer (score 1):

I helped someone a few days ago with something similar. What if you used the following [***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/R5zCV/1/)

Basically setting the left side a fix width and the right side a resizable width

```
.left {width:100%; height:20px; background-color:red; float:left; margin-left:-320px; display:inline}
.right {width:320px; height:20px; background-color:blue; float:right; display:inline}
```